# DL4J UI: How to display cost error of the validation test?

Tags: performance, neural-network, deeplearning4j, dl4j

I use DL4J and I attach the UI.
How can I display on UI the cost error of the **validation set**?
What have I to configure?

I have to check if there is overfitting but the UI display only the cost error of the **training set**. See the image attached below
[image]

DL4J version: 1.0.0-beta3

Answer (score 0):

The separation of the training and test set has to be taken care of by the developer, so you have to provide the validation set just like you provided the training set.

The process is pretty much the same after that.

Comment: I use KFoldIterator so I fit the model on training set and eval on validation set. I don't know how to display the cost of validation set without call back the method "fit" on validation set but I think this is wrong because train the model also on validation set!